# How to show a login form when clicked on sign-in link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to show a login form when a click is done on a link . i want to make default  behaviour of div "hide ".. how can i do that ? may form is by default showing on page., please help me .  it will b grate ful for you .

```
<a href=""  class="signin"  onclick="">Sign In</a>

<div class="form">        
    <input type="text" value="" name="myinput" id="myinput"/>
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('.signin').click(function() {    
        $('.form').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: in CSS - **.form { display:none; }** - the *.show()* method from jquery changes this to *display:block*

Answer (score 2):

Add style to the "form" to hide it.

```
<div style="display:none;" class="form">        
    <input type="text" value="" name="myinput" id="myinput"/>
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set display property of form class to none as shown belo in using css.

```
<a href=""  class="signin"  onclick="">Sign In</a>

<div class="form">
     <input type="text" value="" name="myinput" id="myinput"/>
     <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
.form{
display:none;
}
```

javascript:

```
 $(document).ready (function()
    {

    $('.signin').click(function()
    {    
       $('.form').show();
       $('.signin').hide();

    });
});
```